# Working with BeginTransaction in c# with autocommit

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a question related to transactions between C# 2012 and SQL Server 2008R2.

Suppose I need to call a stored procedure in C# and I want to use the BeginTransaction method of SqlConnection Class to have a better control of the process.

If the database has autocommit, it means that if I open MSMS and update a column of a table, I don't need to explicitly commit my update. In this case that I'm executing the sp using BeginTransaction is not going to insert it before I do Commit right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeginTransaction will start an explicit transaction and therefore not be auto-committed: [Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)